# Отладчик в notepad++ для Java

Tags: java, notepad++

Как делать пошаговую отладку программы написанной на java, если я пишу в notepad++?

Answer (score 1):

Notepad такие вещи не поддерживает, ибо это всего лишь редактор для текста(кода в том числе). Используйте IDE для более тесной интеграции с java, можно поискать плагины или инструменты, но все это есть из коробки в хорошей IDE(Eclipse, IDEA), либо как указали выше, логируйте, выводите нужные данные в файл.

Вообще, если Вы выбрали редактор для своих нужд, то выбирайте java-редактор, такой как jEdit, для которого и плагинов тьма специализированных.

Answer (score 0):

Сэр знает толк в извращениях. (c) анекдот. Используйте вот такой ( [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigor)) notepad++ и не морочьте людям голову.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Используйте логгирование. Или аналитически ищите проблему. Умение читать код (даже свой) - ключевое умение. Отладчик хотя и экономит много времени, отдаляет вас от этого умения.

Штука в том, что отладчик, встроенный в JVM управляется через JDWP-протокол. Протокол этот несложный, но бинарный. Все приличные IDE его давно реализовали и поддерживают пошаговую отладку. Теоретически, можно было бы написать что-то типа gdb для Java (а может такое и имеется даже, но мне не известно об этом), только в этом нет необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы без IDE отлаживать код на java используйте jdb - [The Java Debugger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html). Но вообще-то это очень неудобно и трудоемко, поэтому лучше потратить время и привыкнуть к Eclipse или NetBeans.

Можно ли подключить jdb к Notepad++, мне неизвестно. Думаю, что нельзя.